# Too many open files Error in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-foundry, filehandle, resource-leak

I have a java (tomcat / spring based) cloud multi-tenant application running on cloud foundry, which uses a cloud database. We use `tomcat jdbc` for connection pooling with maximum 8 connections per tenant. We have max wait configured for 60 seconds on connections in `tomcat jdbc`. We cache connection for 300 tenants at any given time.

Recently we experienced `Too many open files` Error.

When we checked `lsof`, we had some interesting findings:

1. There were 191 entries for each jar in `lsof` output. Does it mean, the jar file is being opened for each request?
2. There were many socket connections (to Cloud Database and Load Balancer - We have one http call to another micro-service in some calls) in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

We further checked our dynatrace and found following:

1. We had some `getConnection` calls which failed with Broken Pipe error during `borrowConnection` (reconnect or validate), after 10 mins. I am not sure why `max wait` was not honoured, and is the socket closed after the Broken Pipe.
2. Eventually `getConnection` and `jar loading` (Don't know, why jar is being loaded again) started failing with `Too many open files` Error.

We also don't see any connection leak as it would resulted in `PoolExhaustedException` not the current one.

Any ideas / hints on what is going wrong?

Comment: Hard to say what is going on exactly, but unless your app is doing something particularly disk intensive, "too many open files" typically means too many open network connections. Linux considers them to be "files" as well, so open network connections will count to the limit. Look at `VCAP_APPLICATION`, it has a `limits` section which will tell you how many open files your app instance can have. I can't speak to your environment, but it's usually in the thousands, so a couple of hundred db connections or open jar files is usually a small fraction of the total.

Comment: Are you expecting your application to be very busy? If it has a lot of traffic, you might be just hitting the point where you need to scale up and add more instances. Each instance has its own file limit so you can scale the max open files by adding more instances.

Comment: @DanielMikusa: I checked by doing ssh on application. The limit is ~32000. We already have scaling in place. The app has minimum 3 instances and max 6 instances.

Comment: @DanielMikusa: Can the broken pipe error while accessing DB leak file handle?

Comment: I recommend running `cf env` and looking at `VCAP_APPLICATION`. When you `cf ssh` into a container, the environment is not always the same as the environment where the app is running. I don't know if that would impact how you are checking the limits, but I do know that what is reported in `VCAP_APPLICATION` will always be correct.

Comment: @DanielMikusa: It is 32768 in `VCAP_APPLICATION`

Comment: @DanielMikusa: Today I took the lsof dump when the count was close to 17K (It happened after few days). Most of the entries (~16.5 K) looks like following:
`java      7 vcap  128u     sock                0,8      0t0 1365000653 protocol: TCP`
As JAVA application, we make only http calls - from our app there seems no connection leak. Even the count of open http connections in lsof were in few hundreds. The netstat didn't provide anything interesting but sockstat shows TCP alloc count as ~65K and TCP mem as ~30K. Any clues - what we can do to proceed further...

Comment: The open jars should correspond to the classpath of the running tomcat plus the classpath elements of web-apps and other services. They shouldn't be opened per request, only when a request hits new codebase of a loaded service. If you had 100 webapps each containing same jar I'd expect to see 100 file handle use of that jar path, whereas 100 webapps could use same server classpath jar for as one filehandle.

Comment: @DuncG: Yes, you are right. I think the command I ran printed it per tenant. So, I again ran command when there were too many open file handles and it’s result is in my previous comment.

Comment: @Kumar Can you run `netstat -pnta` (or `ss -pnta`) when the count is close to 17K ?